# Options for .NET 6.0 web app that consumes a web service

Tags: .net-6.0

With .NET 6.0, what options are available for creating a web application that consumes an api/web service?  Example: the web service might have a /cars endpoint and I need to perform a GET against this endpoint and then display the resulting data in a table on a webpage.

Is it possible for Visual Studio to automatically generate code for calling web service endpoints, from the API's definition file (JSON), and maybe even code for the View?

Are there any tutorials for creating a .NET 6.0 web application that consumes a web service (or even .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5.0)?  I search but am not finding any.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have two options:

1. Using autogenerated proxy classes.
2. Using your own code.

1 Can be done by Visual Studio (add Service Reference) or with svcutil.exe

2 Creating an interface (contract) and some code. Example:
Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPingService
{
 [OperationContract]
 string Ping(string msg);
}
```

Code:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://server/PingService.svc"));
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory(binding, endpoint);
var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
var result = serviceClient.Ping("Ping");
channelFactory.Close();
```